# Metamask is not detected automatically while loading Dapp in Production build , but it does load when hosted on localhost

Tags: solidity, metamask

///GetWeb3.js ///

```
import Web3 from "web3";
        
const getWeb3 = async () => {  
  let web3;   
  if (typeof window.ethereum !== "undefined") {   
     web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);  
     console.log(web3)  
  } else {  
    alert(  
        "No wallet detected....  Please install metamasak or any other Wallet!"  
     );    
  }    
  return web3;  
};  

export default getWeb3;
```

////////
///App.js////

```
  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      
      (async () => {
        setWeb3Loading(true);
        const Web3 = await getWeb3();
        setWeb3(Web3);
        const accounts = await Web3.eth.getAccounts();
        setAccounts(accounts[0]);
        setWeb3Loading(false);
        const contract = new Web3.eth.Contract(ABI, Address);
        setContract(contract);
      })();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }

    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);
```